# Slide div. Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this code to slide divs off the screen:

```
       $('.box').click(function() {

            $(this).animate({
                 left: '-50%'
             }, 500, function() {
            $(this).css('left', '150%');
            $(this).appendTo('#container');
            });

            $(this).next().animate({
                 left: '50%'
            }, 500);
       });
```

html:

```
     <div id="container">

     <div id="box1" class="box">Div #1</div>
     <div id="box2" class="box">Div #2</div>
     <div id="box3" class="box">Div #3</div>


      </div>
```

css:
          .box {
             position: absolute;
             left: 150%;
             margin-left: -25%;
          }

```
       #box1 {

         left: 50%;
       }
```

It works great. But when I click on the last div, the first one comes back and I can go over all the div again.

I would like it to stop when the last div appears. Could you give me hints on how I can accomplish that?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
$('.box').one('click' , function() {
```

Also it's a better practice to cache the reoccurring selectors to reduce the number of times you query the **DOM**

```
$('.box').one('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (this.id !== 'box3') {
        $this.animate({
            left: '-50%'
        }, 500, function() {
            $this.css('left', '150%');
            $this.appendTo('#container');
        });

        $this.next().animate({
            left: '50%'
        }, 500);
    }
});​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/mLBMf/2/)**

Comment: Thank you. But the problem is that when we click on the last div, we get the first one again. I would like to disable the slide for the last div.

Comment: ok.. By last div you mean `<div id="box3"` because you can click the divs in any order right

Comment: Yes. I tried with what I want to do, but it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/mLBMf/1/

Comment: Try moving the condition before you start animation.. Try this http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/mLBMf/2/

Comment: It looks like the problem comes from the "position:absolute". Any idea on why this could cause the problem?

Comment: @Marcolac .. Glad to have helped :)